# .data, information pulling through as NaN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to build a simple page, which will calculate your stake and work out your return, like a betting shop.

So far, I have it working by hard coding in my odds. But as you will see in my code, I have the odds pulling through in an alert, which works well. My issue is trying to incorporate this variable into my html, I get the output of "NaN", but I have no clue why! My attempt is commented out, but hopefully this is an easy fix, which I just can't see!

My HTML:

```
 <html>

<head>
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <title></title>
   <script type = "text/javascript" 
   src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {

      $.getJSON("http://localhost:8888/json.json", function(result){

         $.each(result, function(i, field){
     //create an element and append data attribute to the element - in this case field name
     el = $("<div class='bet-block'>" + field.name + field.odds.numerator+"/" + field.odds.denominator + " </div>").data("name", field.name).data("odds", field.odds.numerator+"/" + field.odds.denominator);

     //append element to DOM
     $(".bets").append( el );
  })
      //define a click handler for all new elements to display data in a div
      $(document).on( "click", ".bet-block", function() {
         $(".bet-name").text( $( this ).data("name") );
         $(".bet-odds").text( $( this ).data("odds") );
      });
   });


      function calculate_odds() {
        var winnings = 0,
        betting_amount = $(".stake").val();

        var current_odds = $('.bet-odds').text();


        // THIS ECHOS CORRECT ODDS
        alert(current_odds);

        winnings = (2/1) * betting_amount;
        // winnings = (current_odds) * betting_amount;

        $('.js-winnings').text(winnings); 
     }

     $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".stake").keyup(function(){
         calculate_odds();
      });
   });
  });

</script>
</head>

<body>

   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="bets">
               <h1>All Bets</h1>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="slip">
               <h1>My Bet Slip</h1>
               <div class="new-bet-slip">
                  <p><span class="bet-name"></span> to win @ <span class="bet-odds"></span></p>
                  <input class="stake" type="number" name="betting-amount" min="1" max="5">
                  <div class="bet-return">
                  <span>£</span><span class="js-winnings">0.00</span>
                  </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

My JSON:

```
[{"name":"name1","odds":{"numerator":10,"denominator":1}},[{"name":"name2","odds":{"numerator":5,"denominator":2}}, [{"name":"name3","odds":{"numerator":2,"denominator":1}}, ]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when and where does your `NaN` (which stands for not a number) error appear? maybe here `el = $("<div class='bet-block'>" + field.name + field.odds.numerator+"/" + field.odds.denominator + " </div>").data("name", field.name).data("odds", field.odds.numerator+"/" + field.odds.denominator);` ?

Comment: Isn't `$.each` meant to be `$.each(function(field, i) {`?

Comment: The alert is getting the correct odds, so that works.. 
But..

 winnings = (2/1) * betting_amount; - This works as its a hard coded odd.

 winnings = (current_odds) * betting_amount;  - this gives me NaN

Comment: try : `winnings = (2/1) * parseInt(betting_amount)`

Comment: if betting_amount is a string,winnings will be NAN

Comment: betting_ammount is 10/1 for example

Comment: My fiddle using your code works fine? https://jsfiddle.net/4nLb4cc0/ The only issue is you need to select an odds first otherwise the alert fails.

Comment: obviously current_odds is a string,is current_odds is well formatted number?

Comment: @gavin, thanks for the JSFiddle, If you change the winning = (2/1) to the commented line you will see the issue

Comment: @gujefers How can I change this to make it work? Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: @jdloader just convert it to int: `winnings = parseInt(current_odds) * parseInt(betting_amount)`

Comment: @NishanthMatha that worked! Can you explain a little on what this does for me, for future reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @gujefers pointed out: Your `current_odds` which is declared as:

```
var current_odds = $('.bet-odds').text();
```

Returns `string` refer to http://api.jquery.com/text/

So when you try to do `arithmetic operation` on string which is `*` in `winnings = (current_odds) * betting_amount;` You get `NaN` (not a number) error.

So the safe bet would be try converting the string value to int. `parseInt` function converts `string` to `int`

for example try this is console:

```
var a = '1';
var b = parseInt(a);
console.log(typeof(a)); //this will return string 
console.log(typeof(b)); //this will return number
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON data you entered is not formatted properly, check the square brackets and try again. This site is helpful for that purpose: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: I was just about to point this out, however that wouldn't account for the error OP is reporting. Infact, it wouldn't even reach his code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you...

```
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:8888/json.json", function(result){

 //parse the json & try
       var data= jQuery.parseJSON(result);

         $.each(data, function(i, field){
          //do your action
          console.log(field.name)
               $.each(field.odds, function(k, level2){
                    console.log(level2.numerator,level2.denominator)
               });


       });
  });
```